# How to store key value pair in array where key is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

If array is treated as an object and if I create an array called the person and pass on the code

```
 var person = []
 person.name = "abhishek"
```

It outputs as

```
[name : 'abhishek']
```

What to write a code to store [ 0:'abhishek']

I have tried doing

```
person["0"]="abhishek"
person.0="abhishek"
```

But nothing seems to work

Comment: please add `person` with initialization.

Comment: "the it outputs as [name : 'abhishek']" this is incorrect. It outputs as an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works great, although, if you're using keys, you should probably use an object, not an array.

```
const person = []; 
person["name"] = 'fred';
person["age"] = 30;

console.log(person)

console.log(person["name"]); // fred
console.log(person["age"]); // 30
```

You are assigning values to a key, and **you have to use the same key** to get the same value.  This will not work:

```
const person2 = []; 
person2["name"] = 'fred';

person2[0]; // undefined
person2["name"]; // fred
```

If you want the index, just use that, no quote:

```
const person3 = []; 
person3[0] = 'fred'; 
person3[5] = 'john'; 

console.log(person3[0]) // fred
console.log(person3[5]) // john
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution.

```js
var person = [];
person.push("abhishek");
console.log(person[0]);

OR

person[1] = "Alok"
console.log(person[1]);
console.log(person);
```